# Where would "Class.forName()" in a Maven mojo get a class from?

Tags: java, maven, gradle

I'm working on implementing a Gradle plugin that provides the same functionality that a Maven plugin does.

One thing that the Mojo does is load a class that is specified by a configuration property for the plugin.  It does it with a simple "Class.forName()".  It doesn't attempt to limit the classpath used for this.

I'm wondering exactly what classpath will be used to load the class.  The POM that uses this plugin will specify many dependencies in multiple scopes (at least compile, test, and provided).  Will it search through all loaded dependencies, no matter what scope?

Comment: Yes it will search through all the dependancies .    it is a concept of reflaction.

Comment: I'm confused, are we talking Maven or Gradle here. You say you're writing a Gradle plugin, yet you say "the POM that uses this plugin"?

Comment: I'm writing the Gradle plugin to replace the same functionality in the Maven plugin.  I have to understand what the Maven plugin is doing in order to properly implement the Gradle plugin. I had a related question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28992905/in-a-gradle-plugin-how-to-load-a-class-from-a-specific-configuration .